# How bad is long term bending load on PVC pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pvc

I have plumbed in a garbage disposer under kitchen sink yesterday using PVC piping and plumbing glue - pretty much what was there, but I added the garbage disposer.

The problem is, the pipe that comes out from under the kitchen cabinets and goes down there into the floor after the trap is now slightly under load due to the way garbage disposer fits. Trap pushes the pipe down a bit, this pulls the end that is behind the cabinet a bit up. The pipe itself seems to be quite loose when disconnected from the trap as if inside the wall there is some flexible connection(? is it possible?).

Is it normal for sink plumbing to be slightly under load when system is finished or is it absolutely a bad idea and I should re-do everything so that there is no load at all and the pipe that goes into the cabinets and floor is as loose as it gets?

Comment: Are you saying you tied the disposal into the line with out a p trap? I read this several times and it sounds that way to me. As far as some loading on PVC a little is normal in most cases but a lot may cause leaks.

Comment: Oh, no no, trap is there, just the whole assembly of pipes including trap under my sink is pushed down a bit due to the garburator install, trap connects to pipe that goes into the wall/floor pivoting it a bit - that's where the load on in-wall/floor pipe happens.

Comment: I see some loading regularly one way to relieve a bit of stress is to use a heat gun and heat the pipe evenly all the way around and it will relax a bit.

Comment: Try swapping a pipe, like from disposer to drain, with a flexible pipe. Also, make sure your disposer is firmly attached to the sink. The sink should carry almost all the weight of the disposer. You might also try shortening the pipe, if it's too long, it could cause it to bend.

Comment: Thank you gentleman. I am worried about flexible pipe due to ridges food from dispenser might accumulate. But a heat gun is something I will give a try. Worst case scenario, I can always scrap and repipe - it only costs a few bucks for pipes and connections.